# Discord.js Antiraid bot (detect botwave)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on an Discord Antiraid bot that should detect when a server is raided by user accounts. Currently i just put each member in an array and remove this member after 10 seconds. If the array length is more than 10 it is a raid and all users in this array are getting banned. However, i am not completely satisfied with this method. Does anyone have any other suggestions for me?

Comment: I think you could use that, and check if the members joined within a day or something?

Answer (score 0):

Check how new the accounts are, check if they have default profile pictures, check if they have anything in common (status, profile picture, etc).